# Django filter only if value is given

Tags: python, django, database, filter

I want to get the number of sites per country. Now if the country is not given, the amount of sites for all countries should be the result. My query looks like:

```
Devices = GatewayDevice.objects.prefetch_related("model").filter(
            model__site__country=country, end_date=None
        )
```

Before I do the query I can check if parameter country is null and give it and other value, like example ALL (doesn't work). How can I handle this?

Comment: you need to return all objects of GatewayDevice if country is not given, right?

Comment: Something like this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60332175/postgre-sql-ignore-the-filtering-condition-if-the-value-is-null/60332232#60332232

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would just be to use `if` statements:

```
if country is None:
    Devices = GatewayDevice.objects.prefetch_related("model").filter(end_date=None)
else:
    Devices = GatewayDevice.objects.prefetch_related("model").filter(
            model__site__country=country, end_date=None
        )
```

Comment: The drawback of this approach is, you have to check values of  all the **`N`** fields

Comment: @ArakkalAbu N fields?

Comment: The case where you want to check the emptiness of `country`, `end_date`, `field_1` ... and `field_N`

Comment: Yes, then you need to write `N` times if loop.